# How do I insert dynamic parameters when importing query results?

Tags: apache-superset

I want to import the value by putting parameters when loading the query itself.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE date = {{date}}
```

When getting results from a big query, I would like to change the part {{date}} above by selecting it from the filter.

Superset imported all the data to filter the data, which is not good for bigquery's performance.

So I want to reduce the range by entering parameters before importing the result itself.

And I want to manipulate that parameter by adding a filter from the dashboard.

In conclusion, I would like to receive the query itself by dynamically converting the parameters.

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Bring more data - where and how are you doing that. What exactly is your problem, etc. The more info, the greater chance that someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [Preset User's Corner](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzg8opP7sG8n0Mi0e8yeqAg) youtube channel, they have made some videos about how to use Jinja Template parameter to filter your virtual datasets created using SQLLab queries.

As this have been modernize in recent versions of Superset, check that you have at least version 1.0 (better if you have 1.1)

Comment: The part I want is this.
Is there a video like this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680487/how-do-i-put-variables-in-superset

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to activate Jinja templating if you have not done this before. To do this, you should add another element to the `FEATURE_FLAGS` dictionary in your `superset_config.py`. Element’s key will be `ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING`, and the value will be True. Here is how it will look like:

```
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
    ...  # your existing flags
    "ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING": True,
}
```

After that, you need to restart your Superset script or container and utilise the power of Jinja templates.

Source: https://medium.com/geekculture/interactive-dashboards-in-apache-superset-ec4a3bf9bc82