# How do I put variables in Apache Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I'd like to use a filter in Apache Superset. However, most examples were to load the results and then apply the filter.

I want to put this in the middle of Query as a variable.
All I found was the WHERE condition at the end.

ex)

```
SELECT a AS a , b AS b , c AS c , d AS d
(
SELECT a,b,c,d 
FROM table
)AS `expr_qry`
WHERE a = '1' -- filter
```

If I make a filter, I brought it to WHERE.

**But what I want is as follows.**

```
SELECT a,b,c,@var1 as d
FROM table
WHERE a = '@var2'
```

Put it in like a variable above.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Superset has support for SQL templating to achieve this.

For example, You can retrieve the value for a specific filter as a list using {{ filter_values() }}

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE 
     account_id in ({{ "'" + "','".join(filter_values('account_id')) + "'" }})
```

Read through the doc for more details https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/sql-templating

Comment: Thank you so much for answering.
However, I couldn't solve this problem and eventually developed it through datastuido.